# Mongoose returns a reference field null in some cases?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I will share the relevant information with you, but please do not hesitate to ask if something is missing.

The project has the following dependencies.

```
"sails": "^1.5.3",
"sails-hook-orm": "^2.1.1",
"mongoose": "^6.7.1",
"mongoose-bcrypt": "^1.10.0",
"mongoose-delete": "^0.5.4",
"mongoose-id-validator": "^0.6.0",
"mongoose-paginate": "^5.0.3",
"mongoose-unique-validator": "^3.1.0",
```

The issue I am facing is that, in some cases, it is data recorded long ago; the reference field returns null instead of the id.

Schema

```
module.exports = {
  orm: 'mongoose,'

  schema: {
    ...
    lastUpdated: {
      type: sails.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Query

```
this.find({}).populate({ path: 'lastUpdated', select: 'username' }))
```

The object are not populated because the field is null. Changing the `lastUpdated` schema to `String` will return the value, but the populate will not work.

I have been trying to change the type and update the Mongoose library version, but I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it is helpful for someone else. The issue was that the object not being retrieved has a soft delete that was made with the `mongoose-delete` plugin.